# How to return the result of a mongo query as an array of the field values rather than array of objects

Tags: database, mongodb

I am using the following query:

```
db.collection_name.find({
    "FIELD1" : "VAULE1", "FIELD2": "VALUE2"
}, {_id : 0, "TARGETFIELD":1})
```

And the result for the query looks something like this:

```
[{
  "TARGETFIELD": "ABC"
},
{
  "TARGETFIELD": "DEF"
}]
```

However I require the result of this query to be an array of the values of the `TARGETFIELD`. I want the result to look like this:

```
["ABC", "DEF"]
```

How can I modify my query?

Comment: The answer is you can't. MongoDB will always return a key-value pair document. You can simply use map function, in your application code, to transform the document into an array of strings.

Comment: Best case, you can write an aggregation pipeline, to achieve something like this: `{ doc: ["ABC", "DEF"]}`.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, thanks! I will use the aggregation pipeline to achieve this.